does not navigate back to the previous page
In the code
document.addEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd, false); 

when a 401 error occurs, it navigates to the "signup" page using location.href="signup". However, clicking the browser's back button doesn't return to the previous page, but instead navigates to a different page. In this case, redirect was not used.
After navigating to the "signup" page using clicking the browser's back button does not return to the previous page but instead navigates to a different page.
After navigating to the "signup" page using location.href="signup", clicking the browser's back button does not return to the previous page but instead navigates to a different page.

Use location.replace('signup') if you want to keep current page out of history
